# Jquery Dialog - dialog fields added multiple times to the DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the Jquery UI to display tabs. In one of the tabs, I have a dialog box. If I navigate to that tab, open the dialog, close it, navigate off the tab then back again and open the dialog, I end up with multiple and duplicate HTML elements in the DOM.

In other words...

I've got my main page setup with tabs:

```
<div id="groupTabs" style="width:600px; height:600px; display:none">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="tab1.aspx"><span>Info</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="tab2.aspx"><span>Associations</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Tab #2 contains a dialog box:

```
<div id="dgEvent">
    <input id="someId">
</div>

...

$("#dgEvent").dialog();
```

I've found that if I open the dialog, navigate away (to another tab) and back again, the next time I open up the dialog I'll end up with duplicate elements both named "someId" in my DOM. This causes problems because when I try to grab the value from someID (i.e, $("#someID").val(), I end up getting the value from the first instance of the dialog.)

Is there a fix to make sure that the fields are removed when the dialog is closed? Or better yet, that they are removed properly when navigating to another tab?

**EDIT**

In the end, I believe the problem is related to the use of Tabs and Dialog together. Any field I have on the form that is outside the dialog gets removed from the DOM when I navigate off the tab. However, anything that was in the dialog remains in the DOM after I navigate away. Thus, when I navigate back, I end up with duplicates.

Comment: Sigh, it's sad when I find my problem in an unanswered form on S. O. Guess I'll take my 10 dialog boxes and go home.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
$('#your-dialog').dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Destroy the dialog and then remove the div with it's children from the DOM with `remove()`.

Regards.

Comment: .dialog("destroy") Useful stuff what resetting settings for ContentDiv

Answer (score 3):

I had similar experience.
My problem was caused by having a popup `<div>` inside a `updatepanel`.
After a `ajax` call, a new duplicate is created.
To solve this problem, just avoid putting the popup `<div>` inside an `updatepanel`.
Instead, put the `updatepanel` inside the popup `<div>`.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#dgEvent").dialog();`, try creating the dialog so that it doesn't auto-open, then use open and close to show/hide the dialog:

```
$("#dgEvent").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$("#dgEvent").dialog('open');
$("#dgEvent").dialog('close');
```

See the overview section of the [jQuery UI Dialog page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), which references [this blog post](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/).

Comment: @Chu, you could try `$("#dgEvent").dialog("destroy");` when you navigate away.

Comment: Adrift - Destroy doesn't help either. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using autoOpen:false and also getting duplicate DOM objects every time I close and reopen. It's outside of a jQuery tab, so it may not be the tab causing issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the dialog is being cloned by jQuery UI and placed at the end of the DOM,
before closing the dialog try removing it from the DOM

```
$("#dgEvent").remove();
```

that should fix your issue.