# JQuery UI Dialog and duplicated form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

I am using a JQuery UI Dialog and the ajax submit plugin from malsup.com.

The issue is that the UI Dialog (I believe that is the culprit) is duplicating the fields of the form. It would not be such an issue except that this form is for uploading multiple files. The form uses a DataTable.

Apart from the duplicating fields the process is fine.

I am not re-using the dialog, which would duplicate the fields (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740500/jquery-dialog-dialog-fields-added-multiple-times-to-the-dom) )

The page gets the form and submits it through ajax: here is the code:

```
function smxTableDialogForm ( aURL, tableId, row ) {

    var lData = "";
    var lURL = aURL.split("?");
    var lDialog;
    if (lURL.length == 2){
       lData = lURL[1]; 
       lURL = lURL[0]
    };

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: lURL,
       data: lData,
       dataType: "json"
      }).
    done( function(response){
         if ( response.success ){
           lDialog = $("<div></div>").dialog( {
              height: "auto",
              maxHeight: 800,
              width: 750,
              autoOpen: false,
              buttons: [
                { text: "Save",
                  icons: {primary: "ui-icon-check" },
                  click: function () {
                    smxAjaxSubmit(response.formid);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
                },
                { text: "Cancel",
                  icons: {primary: "ui-icon-close"},
                  click: function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                }
              }],
              close: function (event, ui) { 
                  $(this).remove(); 
              },
              resizable: false,
              modal: true
           });

          lDialog.html(response.content);

          lDialog.dialog("open");
         }
         else {
             $.alert(response.message, response.title);
          };
        }).
        fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           $.alert("Sorry, no info to display.", "oops");
        });

};

function smxAjaxSubmit (aFormId) {

    $("#" + aFormId).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(){
          $.blockUI({ message: '<h3><img src="/sysimages/ajaxloader.gif" /> Just a moment...</hr>' });
        },
        complete: function(){
          $.unblockUI();
        },
        success: function(response) {       
          alert(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           $.alert("Problem. status: " + textStatus + "; error: " + errorThrown, "oops");
        }
    });
};
```

Any ideas gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's the dialog? It simple hides/shows the content inside it's `div`.

Comment: agreed this also happens when I use the bootstrap 3 dialog. I'll post as a new question as this is so old.